# drawing charts with the help of javascript and HTML5 in android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I was going on through certain ways and codes to draw charts and graphs, I found many libraries some free some commercial etc.,but at last i draw it on canvas,One thing which I found interesting is to draw with the help of javascript and HTML5.
For reference:
[enter link description here](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=5424397F3130CE7769FF47DD67742911?recipeId=851&recipeFrom=ViewTOC)

I have no idea how to do this dyanamically(not with the fixed values),I really want to use it,but i don't know javascript or HTML so i am unable to go ahead,It would be a great help if you would be able to tell me, how to do this with dynamic values.(either by accessing the database or any other way if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access db in java and inject results to the javascript by using

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:refreshData(someDynamicContent)");
```

Comment: and how to recieve it from the other side,it will be really helpful if you elaborate it little more.

Comment: You have to create the javascript function that handle the new data... I don't know what type of data your are manipulating...

Comment: i have to send float type values.

Comment: Try reading this part of the webview documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: I'm talking about the addJavascriptInterface function... Maybe it can be useful... But if you can't produce javascript code, it can be hard... As to update the html charts, you will need to write sole javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting your "dynamic values" from (the user or a database)? Regardless you will need to know at least a little html and javascript. Google Charts has some really nice libraries for this.

Comment: i think if i will be able to access the database with javascript then it will be great, but i don't know how to access database with javascript.

Comment: Javascript is client-side only, so you can't access values stored on the server with it directly. However you can use javascript to request a server side script (e.g. PHP, ASP...) which can access the database. I would definitely figure out how you will be retrieving data before looking at how to display it to the end user.

Comment: If you give me more details I would be happy to help though. What database system are you using, who is hosting your site, etc.